# Cannot send chat invites anymore from Openfire user to GMAIL account

Tags: gmail, xmpp, openfire

I have an Openfire server with some custom users that act as bots and send chat invites to GMAIL accounts.

After 6 month of working perfectly well, suddenly, since yesterday, my users cant send anymore chat invites to GMAIL, since today. They just don't receive invites anymore. I didn't change anything nor install the new Openfire version. Just happened.

If I do it the opposite way, from a Gmail account I invite a Openfire user, it still doesn't work, but I check the server and there are subscription sent as "none". I have to change to subscription type to "both" and then it works. But I need it to be from my Openfire TO Gmail accounts.

Everything works good if the GMAIL account is a Google Hosted Domain with DNS configured correctly. Also, any other XMPP server like JABBER works fine also.

It seems that something suddenly changed on Gmail side. I'm quiet lost, I don't know what to check, what to change to make it work again. My Live Chat service relies on this and I had to stop accepting new users...

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: More data to my issue:
 
I have several bots with a roster of thousands of gmail accounts. Could it be that  I reached  a  rate  limit  on  google?
 
Please help me, thank you

Comment: did you manage to resolve that problem or have any progress / better understanding of it? Seems I have the same one and completely lost.

Comment: Thank  you for your response Pavel. I also read your reply on google forums and stackoverflow

It makes sense what you say, but, yesterday I signed up for an account to a chat service similar to mine, and this service managed to send me the chat invites to my gmail account.
Then I subscribed for another 2 live chat services and didn't receive the invites. They say that it could take 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible explanation to this problem http://mail.jabber.org/pipermail/operators/2013-March/001610.html.

```
GoogleTalk now has whitelist of servers to connect with to avoid invite spam.
```

Comment: I will be waiting for that whitelist to be published